# error to fetch array from dictionary list in vba

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

in my project in vba i have 2 combobox like this:

```
combobox1=zahedan,zabol
combobox2=621,54130
```

and 2 arrays which i declare to save list of subitems zahedan and zabol. i use a dictionary to fetch selected array when combobox1 change like this:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Dim dicArrays As Scripting.Dictionary

Dim hoze621code
Dim hoze621name

Dim hoze54130code
Dim hoze54130name
```

when form active program do somethings like below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

  hoze621code = Array(54101, 54102)
  hoze621name = array("test1", "test2")

  hoze54130code = Array(5421, 5422)
  hoze54130name = array("test3", "test4")

  Set dicArrays = New Scripting.Dictionary
     dicArrays.Add "hoze621name", hoze621name
     dicArrays.Add "hoze621code", hoze621code

     dicArrays.Add "hoze54130name", hoze54130name
     dicArrays.Add "hoze54130code", hoze54130code
```

now when i use combobox1.change to fetch list of selected area it show me runtimes error 91 or 13? this is combobox1.change code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim arrayname2(), arraycode2() As String

  arrayname2 = dicArrays("hoze" & ComboBox2.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex) & "name")
  arraycode2 = dicArrays("hoze" & ComboBox2.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex) & "code")
  // do somthings with selected array

End Sub
```

i think it's ok but not working! any body to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited**: to add some info about variables scoping

not so clear how the code you showed is spread over your project modules

for me to have something that compiled I had to declare as `Public` thse variables to be shared between UserForm code and module and/or worksheet code, like follows

```
'code where Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() is placed
Option Explicit
Public hoze621code
Public hoze621name

Public hoze54130code
Public hoze54130name

Public dicArrays As Scripting.Dictionary
```

next, for sure you have to declare both `arrayname2()` and `arraycode2()` variables  as of `Variant` type

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim arrayname2() As Variant, arraycode2() As Variant

    arrayname2 = dicArrays("hoze" & ComboBox2.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex) & "name")
    arraycode2 = dicArrays("hoze" & ComboBox2.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex) & "code")

  'do somthings with selected array
  ' like:
    Dim i As Long
    MsgBox "arrayname2 has " & UBound(arrayname2) + 1 & " elements"
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrayname2)
        MsgBox vbTab & "element " & i & ": " & arrayname2(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: it show me error `object variable or with block variable not set `

Comment: too vague a clue...what line actually throws the error?  And possibly post the minimum description to have people here understand what variables are defined where (modules code pane, userform code pane, sheets code pane..)

Comment: the line `arrayname2 = dicArrays("hoze" & ComboBox2.List(ComboBox1.ListIndex) & "name")`

Comment: can i have ur email to send excel file!

Comment: post it in your question as a link